setData() triggered when press "Space" key at listView
I have a small app in PySide6, which uses Qt Model-View. Presenter is inherited from QAbstractItemModel.
When I press "space" key, one of selected items is checked (setData() is called in my presenter module), which is not intentional behavior.
What I want to do is:

Make Items user-checkable
And yet avoid checking Items by space key (as when multiple Items are selected, only one will be checked by space)


I did not set up any actions to capture space key, and I set edit triggers to NoEditTriggers:
self.ui.listView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.EditTrigger.NoEditTriggers)

and checked that it is not reset during app lifetime.
So here is the main question: can I disable or control this behavior or maybe it is a bug of PySide6?
And auxiliary question: how can I trace, which methods invoke setData()? Currently, I see only setData() in Stack Trace.
Thank you in advance!

You're not showing nor telling what model you're using, but I'm going to assume you're using a QStandardItemModel or QAbstractItemModel subclass. In the first case, you have to use setCheckable(False) on all new items, in the second you must not provide the Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable enum when returning from flags(). And no, there's no easy way to know what invoked setData() as those calls are done on the C++ side, they're not made from Python.

@musicamante, begging pardon, updated the question. Yes, I use QAbstractItemModel, but the problem is that I just need to avoid this space key behavior (maybe redefine it). Totally removing the checkability is not what I try to reach. Thanks for answer for 2-nd part, though some (maybe difficult) way may exist. Exploring.

If you want to keep items checkable, I would discourage completely disabling the keyboard checking, as that's a known convention very common in people using keyboard navigation: you may consider changing its behavior so that pressing the space bar results in toggling selected items (using the current index as reference state to change, in case of inconsistent states). Would that be acceptable? For the tracing, since we should only ask one question (or a few strictly related questions) per post, consider creating a new question in case you cannot find out anything on your own.

I eventually found some answer to my question at https://qtcentre.org/threads/21332-ItemIsUserCheckable-and-checking-all-selected-items. Here are some considerations at this topic:

If extended selection is used in QListView, and items are user-checkable, then pressing "Space" leads to checking of the last selected item. This is no bug, and it works this way for QListView and QListWidget for both Qt and PySide;
I found no simple way to change this behavior (setEditTriggers() does not affect it);
As mentioned by @musicamante, there is no simple way to trace, which method called setData() in that case.

Solution

If you work in PySide6-designer (or Qt Creator), select "Promote to..." option for QListView and create transformed class, which inherits from QListView (otherwise, just create your custom class, which inherits from QListView),
Reimplement keyPressEvent() method there. E. g., following way:

  def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Space:
      self._checkAllSelected()
    else:
      super().keyPressEvent(event)

Here _checkAllSelected() is new function, which would handle checking of items. I implemented it following way:
  def _checkAllSelected(self):
    model = self.model()
    indexes = self.selectedIndexes()
    setCheckState = Qt.CheckState.Unchecked
    for index in indexes:
      if model.data(index, Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole) == Qt.CheckState.Unchecked:
        setCheckState = Qt.CheckState.Checked
        break
    for index in indexes:
      model.setData(index, setCheckState.value, Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)

Now checking of items in case of multiple selection can be managed.

Check state toggling using the space bar is a common convention, coming from the checkbox/radio controls (when focused), and since it's also an expected convention, it should not be modified.
The edit triggers have nothing to do with state toggling, because those triggers are used to enter the edit mode (normally, create an editor for the current item), which does not happen when toggling an item, nor prevents setting model data.
All keyboard interaction (including navigation, selection and state changes and possible edit mode initialization) is implemented starting from the keyPressEvent() of the view, which eventually sends the event to the delegate.
When the user presses the space bar, the view eventually calls the delegate's editorEvent(), which checks if the index is enabled and user checkable, and finally calls the model's setData() with the next possible check state.
Since disabling that feature may be annoying to users that use the keyboard a lot, what you can do is to "extend" that convention so that toggling is applied to all selected items.
class ExtendedToggleList(QListView):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() != Qt.Key.Key_Space or len(self.selectedIndexes()) <= 1:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
            return

        current = self.currentIndex()
        selected = self.selectedIndexes()
        if current not in selected:
            current = selected[-1]
        if current.data(Qt.CheckStateRole) == Qt.CheckState.Unchecked:
            newState = Qt.CheckState.Checked
        else:
            newState = Qt.CheckState.Unchecked
        for index in selected:
            self.model().setData(index, newState, Qt.CheckStateRole)

If you really want to disable using the space bar at all, then you just need to call the super().keyPressEvent(event) only in case the event key is not Key_Space.
